# React.js - Cannot read property of undefined, even though context is bound (call parent method from child)

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I am building a small app in React -- trying to call a function from my parent component `Job` when a bar from a bar chart (ApexCharts) is clicked in a child component `SummaryChart`.

Naturally, the way I have read to do this is to define a function in Job called `getSequenceView`, and pass it in a prop to Chart under the alias `handleBarClick`, then call `this.props.handleBarClick` from `SummaryChart` to invoke it in the parent.

## Parent Component

```
class Job extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      ...
    }

    this.getSequenceView = this.getSequenceView.bind(this);

  }

  getSequenceView(config, event)
  {
    console.log(config.someData);
    $('#help-modal').modal();
  }

render()
  {
    return (
      
      <SummaryChart
        handleBarClick={this.getSequenceView}
      />

    );
  }
```

## Child Component

```
class SummaryChart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {
      options: {
        chart: {
          events: {
            dataPointSelection:  function(event, chartContext, config) {
              this.props.handleBarClick();
            },
        }
     }
  }

  render() {
    return (

          <Chart
            options={this.state.options}
            series={this.state.series}
            type="bar"
            width="100%"
          />
    );
  }
}
```

[ApexCharts docs for handling events here!](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/events/#dataPointSelection)

I have a feeling that since I am passing `this.state.options` as a prop to the actual `Chart` object from ApexCharts that when the bar is clicked, the event registers from the `Chart` object instead of `SummaryChart` and perhaps that is why I am receiving the error.

> app.js:66798 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleBarClick'
> of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

In the constructor `this.props` hasn't been set yet.

## Solution

Access the props that were passed to the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    options: {
      chart: {
        events: {
          dataPointSelection: function (event, chartContext, config) {
            props.handleBarClick();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
```